# Attaching an Azure SQL Datebase to Sharepoint Online Provider-hosted Web Forms Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql, azure

I found [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-in-with-sql-database-in-azure/) but it's specifically made for MVC add-ins. I'm looking for a way of attaching my Azure SQL Datebase to a Web Forms Sharepoint Online add in but I can't find it anywhere.

---

It was easier than I expected. Just use any of the many guides for conencting a SQL Server Datebase to ASP.Net Web Forms, like [this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32227.how-to-connect-sql-server-database-to-asp-net-web-forms.aspx).